# JQuery Scroll doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a scrolling action, in which i want to toggle the .clone class with it's transitions. It is working properly in Chrome, yet it is not working on Firefox.
Can someone help me?

**CSS:**

```
header {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;
}

header.clone {
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   top: -65px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 999;
   transition: 0.2s top cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
   -webkit-transition: 0.2s top cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
   -moz-transition: 0.2s top cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
   -o-transition: 0.2s top cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
   -ms-transition: 0.2s top cubic-bezier(.3, .73, .3, .74);
   background: #3E3E3E;
 }
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    $clone  = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("down",(fromTop > 800));
    });
});
```

Comment: A demo would help I suspect since you haven't provided the HTML.

Comment: You should probably use `var fromtop = $(window).scrollTop()`, FF and IE use `html` to scroll and only webkit related browsers use `body` - `window` is the common factor they both bubble up to.

Comment: Since your `scroll` event is called multiple times (way too many), you better cache the jquery objects outside the event. So, your event should look like `$body.toggleClass("down", $window.scrollTop() > 800)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this to better support cross browser scrolling. Use `window` instead of `¨body¨`...

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Rest of code

});
```

Comment: Being exemplary with that reputation and closing the question for example because there's a multitude of duplicates. In any case not semi repeating what was already mentioned for the sake of personal motivation.

Comment: @Shikkediel Sorry. Will take your advice. Thanks.